# Como controlar las dimensiones de la clase <div class="overlay"></div> de Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, css3

El problema que tengo es que cuando tengo la página en pantalla completa se ve perfectamente la capa que oscurece la imagen y el slider, pero cuando voy a mirar la página en el movil, esta parte que se oscurece tiene una dimension fija y falta opacidad en la parte superior y inferior, si me podriais ayudar seria de mucho agradecer, aqui os dejo el codigo HTML y CSS que tengo:

```css
.fonsimg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #080d15;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
 <section id="twitter" class="parallax">
    <div class="fonsimg">
      <a class="twitter-left-control" href="#twitter-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
      <a class="twitter-right-control" href="#twitter-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="uni4 text-center">
              <i><img style="background-color: #080d15;" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7f364aec7e35f0ec454bb6454869de7d?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt=""></i>
              <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="twitter-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>
               <!-- <div class="item">
                  <H4>Lorem Ipsum</H4>
                </div>-->
                <div class="item">
                  <H4>Lorem Ipsum</H4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tus elementos no tienen alto, intenta dar alto al `html` y al `body` de `100%` y después a todos los elementos que están dentro. También elimina el `margin` y el `padding` del `body` para remover el espacio entre este y el borde de la ventana, ejemplo:

> Pon el `snippet` a pantalla completa para que veas la diferencia.

Código CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#twitter,
.fonsimg {
  height: 100%;
}

.fonsimg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #080d15;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<section id="twitter" class="parallax">
  <div class="fonsimg">
    <a class="twitter-left-control" href="#twitter-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
    <a class="twitter-right-control" href="#twitter-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
          <div class="uni4 text-center">
            <i><img style="background-color: #080d15;" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7f364aec7e35f0ec454bb6454869de7d?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt=""></i>
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          </div>
          <div id="twitter-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
              </div>                  
              <div class="item">
                <H4>Lorem Ipsum</H4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```